# Spring MVC update Joda time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, time, jodatime

I'm trying to update Joda DateTime but it don't want to work correctly. When I click on button "Tomorrow's parties" jsp reload my jsp with tomorrow's date of next day, but when I click on button again jsp don't reload with new date. Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem?

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/parties")
public String listOfParties(@ModelAttribute("tomorrow") String day, Model model, Principal principal) {
    DateTime today = new DateTime();
    if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("Tomorrow")) {
        today = today.plusDays(1);
    } 
    DateTime date = today;
    model.addAttribute("parties", partyManager.findAllTodayParties());
    model.addAttribute("date", date);
    return "/parties";
}

@RequestMapping(params = "Tomorrow", value = "/parties", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String nextDay() {   
    return "redirect:/parties";
}
```

Here is my jsp with Spring form for update date:

```
<form:form action="parties" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="tomorrow" value="Tomorrow" />
   <input type="submit" value="Tomorrow's parties" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: deleted previous comment - is this what you are trying to do: user clicks on tomorrow button, you move the date 7 days forward and find the parties for that given day.  Then if user clicks again, you want the date to move two weeks ahead (from the original date)?  If so, why would this call 'DateTime today = new DateTime();' not take you back to the original date (and not 7 days forward to which you can apply another days)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code. It must be today.plusDays(1). Yes, when user click twice on button, he can't to move two days ahead and if I add  button "yesterday" I have same problem.

Comment: You're always starting with `new DateTime()`, which is always the current day (for the JVM's time zone). You'll have to change your starting day to be relative to the previously determined date.

Comment: I understand that I must change my starting day, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: you need to pass in the date as input (instead of caching it somehow on the server, send it from the client to the server where the date will end up being the input.  If there is no input, use the the new Date call (to get the current date)

Comment: @JermySixony I have posted the solution as answer please check and update if not clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you click first time in JSP "Tomorrow" button then you get the Tomorrow date on your jsp and that is your first click.
Once you are having tomorrow date then after next click POST this existing date again to your method, After that assign this value as new date and increment it by one.

Other approach:
You can also use the counter and increase the counter on each click and pass this counter to your method and add it in your date.

i.e.
create one more hiddnen variable in your jsp for counter, once jsp is loading pass this value as 1 from your jsp. After click in your method add one more it and go for tomorrow.

Comment: Counter not working. Input date is always current date. I don't know why?

Comment: In your jsp just add one more hidden variable as counter and set value as for the first time 0 (you can set this value from your method dont hardcode as 0), now click on tomorrow button and pass this value to your method and there change this code `today = today.plusDays(1);` to `today = today.plusDays(counter);` and add one more line as `counter++;` and set this counter again so that jsp page the value will come 2 ,

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna thank you guys for really helping me out!!! I solved my problem. Here is my solution.

JSP with Spring form:

```
    <form:form action="parties" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="day" value="${date.getDayOfYear()+1)}" />
      <input type="submit" value="Tomorrow's parties" />
    </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
   @RequestMapping("/parties")
   public String listOfParties(@ModelAttribute("day") String day, Model model) {

   DateTime date = partyManager.newDay(day);
   model.addAttribute("parties", partyManager.findAllTodayParties());
   model.addAttribute("date", date);
   return "/parties";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/parties", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String nextDay() {    
   return "redirect:/parties";
   }
```

Method newDay(day) in PartyManager class:

```
   public DateTime newDay(String day) {
   int dayNumber = 0;
   if (StringUtils.isEmpty(day)) {  // Check whether the given String is empty
        dayNumber = new DateTime().getDayOfYear();
   } else {
        dayNumber = Integer.parseInt(day); }
   int newDayNumber = dayNumber;
   DateTime newDate = new DateTime().withDayOfYear(newDayNumber);
   return newDate;
}
```